# 12V in, 1V @ 12 Amp Out, Buck, Why 100 Amp MOSFETS and 60A Inductor?

Tags: mosfet, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, buck, mosfet-driver

I was showing someone the TI Workbench and it came up with this schematic.
94% Efficiency, switching Freq. 100khz

[image]

---

With voltage of 12v and 1v, max Amps of 12, why would it select 25v and 30v 100 Amp MOSFETS?

---

[image]

---

88% Efficiency, Inductor 24 Amp, f<sub>sw</sub>: 230khz

[image]

Comment: Inductors gone wild.

Comment: Cool looking tool though...

Comment: Notice that you have the optimisation knob on the maxEfficiency setting. The difference between 20A and 100A FETs will be rDSon, as well as current. Try it on the minBOM or the minSize settings, it may choose a smaller device.

Comment: @Neil_UK I noticed that, I'm an efficiency freak.  Efficiency OCD.  The design is not real it was just a demo.  I have no clue myself so I was curious.  I backed the efficiency knob to middle of the road and posted the result.  Not much change.

Answer (score 2):

Webench is a nice tool, but sometimes it makes strange suggestions.  You have to use some common sense.  I can't say for sure why it picked this configuration, but I have a couple of potential ideas.  First, each given controller/topology seems to only have a few options for secondary parts like MOSFETs.  The tool simply may not have many options to use with the LM3150, and this is the only one that meets the requirements.

Second, you have selected "optimize for efficiency".  It is possible that it picked these high current MOSFETs to get a low Rds(on) for highest efficiency, even if it is a bit silly.

Comment: I backed off the efficiency and the current are still high, it cranked up the switching frequency.

Comment: Might be an idea to try a few other ICs to see if they come up with less bulky choices.  Also check for those devices that have application designs that approach your chosen operating conditions, they might be a better match.

Comment: Reducing the efficiency from 94% to 88% reduced the Inductor Amps from 60 down to 24V. MOSFETS are cheap compared to a 0.0007 ohm 60A inductor .  BOM dropped from $10.23 to $4.68, the inductor from $5.40 to $0.53.

Answer (score 2):

12W out , loss @ 6%=720mW @ 10A , then R=7.2mΩ  approx including Cout.

Although this neglects duty cycle and higher peak currents, gives you an idea, why high efficiency low V buck regulators often use FETs rated for 10x rated current.

Comment: That makes sense. @Evan concurs.  I've never done a low V buck.  I do like strings of 16 LEDs with 48-54Vin.  I did need to drop the 48 down to 3.3 for a 14 pin AVR that draws a couple of mA.  That I did with a linear.

Comment: So does that apply to the inductor, the amps went up to 60 to get 0.0007 ohms?

Comment: yes,  but all loop resistance adds up to 7 mΩ, so L was <1mΩ